# NodeJs variable always being returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

Hi I have the following code but temp always returns undefined and I have tried passing variables through as parameters but haven't found a solution. How could I get the value of temp to return the correct value. I know that in javascript the order is unimportant however I dont know how to fix that. Thanks

```
function get_account (id){
  temp = "";
  Account.get(id, function (err, acc) {
    temp = acc.get("Account");

 });
 return temp
}
```

Comment: I bet `get_account` *actually* returns an empty string (`""`) ... not `undefined` - also, global variables suck :p

Comment: Please check this block, What is happening in  Account.get(id, function (err, acc) {
    temp = acc.get("Account");

 }); what is happening in Account.get function..?

Comment: If i do console.log(acc.get("Account")) it prints the correct value as a string which is what i expecected

Comment: you need to use `promise` to return the correct value

Comment: Try this ```function get_account(id, callback){
  Account.get(id,function(err, acc){
 if(err){
  return callback(err);
 }else{
  return callback(acc.get(“Account”))
 }
   
  })
}

get_account(id,function(err, callback){
 console.log(callback);
});```